# Can I selectively send scores of my general and subject GRE to the university that I am applying to?

Tags: gre

I made an account for general GRE and subject GRE. I have a pretty bad score in subject GRE. Few universities are not asking for subject GRE score and it would be better if I don't send them subject GRE score. When I try to send my score to university ETS sends both the scores from my account. Is their any way, I can only one score from the account?

Comment: Cannot you send them an email and ask them to help you with your problem? I have heard that candidates who have sit the exam more than once may choose which score to be sent to the institute they are applying to; but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

GRE offers a [ScoreSelect](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/about/scoreselect) function.

> After test day, you can send additional score reports for a fee and select from these options for each report you'd like to send:

- Most Recent option — Send your scores from your most recent test administration.
- All option — Send your scores from all test administrations in the last five years.
- Any option — Send your scores from one OR as many test administrations as you like from the last five years.

You can only send by test date, though, so if you took both tests on the same day, you'll have to send them together. If this is the case, then I don't believe you can get around it.

> You will select by specific test dates, so your scores are all from the same testing session.

This applies to both general and subject GREs.

> The ScoreSelect option is available for both the GRE® revised General Test and GRE® Subject Tests, and can be used by anyone with reportable scores from the last five years.